# Search for partial words using Solr

Tags: solr, sunspot

I'm trying to search for a partial word using Solr, but I can't get it to work.

I'm using this in my `schema.xml` file.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" stemEnglishPossessive="1" splitOnNumerics="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Searching for `die h` won't work, but `die hard` returns some results.
I've reindexed the database after the above configuration was added.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/044b3df379b60defcde7) is the url and output when searching for `die hard`. The debugger is turned on.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/938c8e70db41cb72bbd5) is the url and output when searching for `die h`. The debugger is turned on.

I'm using Solr 3.3. [Here](https://gist.github.com/d56db24c6b581f3f8db2) is the rest of the `schema.xml` file.

Comment: I solved this. go to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824954/solr-partial-and-full-string-match/8247013#8247013

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query you've shared is searching the "title_text" field, but the schema you posted above defines the "text" field.  Assuming this was just an oversight, and the title_text field is defined as in your post, I think a probable issue is that the NGramTokenizer is configured with minGramSize="3", and you are expecting to match using a single-character token.

You could try changing minGramSize to 1, but this will inevitably lead to some very inefficient indexes; and I wonder whether you really are keen on having "e" match every movie with an e in the title?

Comment: Is it possible to define an `NGramTokenizerFactory` for all indexes, not just for `text`? I tried searching for the movie `The Dancing Masters` using `Danci`, which worked. But it didn't work to search for `Danc`, any ideas why? Shouldn't the `NGramTokenizerFactory` limit be set to 3?

Comment: Analysis (tokenizers, etc) are defined per-field in Solr.  If you want to index all the text in all your fields at once, you can define a copyField that does that automatically.  I suspect the "Danci" match is due to tokenization and not NGram.  If you mess around in the admin tool where you can see the results of analysis, you should be able to tell.

Comment: Using copyField worked great. [Here](https://gist.github.com/1272526) is the result. Do you by any chance know any other god filters that I might include in my schema.xml file?

Comment: Wouldn't `title_text` be matched by Sunspot's dynamic `*_text` which has the type `text` defined in the question? So the first sentence in the answer is not relevant?

Comment: lulalala I don't know what Sunspot has to do with this?  The OP didn't mention it.