# Playframework + Lucene: How to search partial words?

Tags: lucene, playframework

I am trying to get partial word search enabled in my application. What I would like to happen is if some one searches for say framework and the index column has "playframework" as one of the items then it should be detected as a hit.

Here is what I tried:

play.modules.search.Query q =  Search.search("index:*" + JavaExtensions.noAccents(by).toLowerCase() + "*", Location.class);

But I get an error:
Cannot parse 'index:*framework* : '*' or '?' not allowed as first character in WildcardQuery

Any ideas?

Comment: You should never begin your search with a '*', like stated. You should define filters to match partials (using NGramFilterFactory probably). see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824954/solr-partial-and-full-string-match for a related question, 2nd answer ( by Mauricio Scheffer) should work. Don't forget to re-index!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to do a [fuzzy search](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches). In your case the following code should do what you need:

```
play.modules.search.Query q = 
  Search.search("yourFieldInLocationClass:" + queryString + "~", Location.class);
```